# Mongodb aggregate, match, group and sort on complex JSON

Tags: json, mongodb, sabre

I receive a large amount of JSON back (flight data) which I've been thinking about using mongo as the tool to query/filter it before returning back to the UI.

Here's the json [response from Sabre (flight search)](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=f90a655cfe10b3ff82b5137b65ab8a56)

```
{
  "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS": {
    "PricedItineraries": {
      "PricedItinerary": [
        {
          "SequenceNumber": 1,
          "AirItinerary": {
            "OriginDestinationOptions": {
              "OriginDestinationOption": [
                {
                  "FlightSegment": [
                    {
                      "DepartureDateTime": "2015-11-12T11:40:00",
                      "ArrivalDateTime": "2015-11-12T17:35:00",
                      "FlightNumber": "1980"
                    },
                    {
                      "DepartureDateTime": "2015-11-12T19:35:00",
                      "ArrivalDateTime": "2015-11-13T02:00:00",
                      "FlightNumber": "760"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "FlightSegment": [
                    {
                      "DepartureDateTime": "2015-11-19T08:25:00",
                      "ArrivalDateTime": "2015-11-19T11:40:00",
                      "FlightNumber": "763"
                    },
                    {
                      "DepartureDateTime": "2015-11-19T12:55:00",
                      "ArrivalDateTime": "2015-11-19T15:05:00",
                      "FlightNumber": "1985"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "AirItineraryPricingInfo": [
            {
              "ItinTotalFare": {
                "TotalFare": {
                  "Amount": 269.56,
                  "CurrencyCode": "GBP"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "SequenceNumber": 2,
          "AirItinerary": {
            "OriginDestinationOptions": {
              "OriginDestinationOption": [
                {
                  "FlightSegment": [
                    {
                      "DepartureDateTime": "2015-11-12T16:45:00",
                      "ArrivalDateTime": "2015-11-12T22:40:00",
                      "FlightNumber": "1986"
                    },
                    {
                      "DepartureDateTime": "2015-11-13T00:40:00",
                      "ArrivalDateTime": "2015-11-13T07:10:00",
                      "FlightNumber": "762"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "ElapsedTime": 640,
                  "FlightSegment": [
                    {
                      "DepartureDateTime": "2015-11-19T08:25:00",
                      "ArrivalDateTime": "2015-11-19T11:40:00",
                      "FlightNumber": "763"
                    },
                    {
                      "DepartureDateTime": "2015-11-19T12:55:00",
                      "ArrivalDateTime": "2015-11-19T15:05:00",
                      "FlightNumber": "1985"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "AirItineraryPricingInfo": [
            {
              "ItinTotalFare": {
                "TotalFare": {
                  "Amount": 269.56,
                  "CurrencyCode": "GBP"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "SequenceNumber": 6,
          "AirItinerary": {
            "OriginDestinationOptions": {
              "OriginDestinationOption": [
                {
                  "FlightSegment": [
                    {
                      "DepartureDateTime": "2015-11-12T11:40:00",
                      "ArrivalDateTime": "2015-11-12T17:35:00",
                      "FlightNumber": "1980"
                    },
                    {
                      "DepartureDateTime": "2015-11-12T19:35:00",
                      "ArrivalDateTime": "2015-11-13T02:00:00",
                      "FlightNumber": "760"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "FlightSegment": [
                    {
                      "DepartureDateTime": "2015-11-19T03:15:00",
                      "ArrivalDateTime": "2015-11-19T06:30:00",
                      "FlightNumber": "761"
                    },
                    {
                      "DepartureDateTime": "2015-11-19T12:55:00",
                      "ArrivalDateTime": "2015-11-19T15:05:00",
                      "FlightNumber": "1985"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "AirItineraryPricingInfo": [
            {
              "ItinTotalFare": {
                "TotalFare": {
                  "Amount": 269.56
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I've been trying to get this into a view that I want but struggling with the complexity of all the nested arrays. My question is how can I achieve a desired result like this:

```
{
    'Price': 269.56, <-- //Group on price (TotalFare)
    'Outbound': [{
        <Outbound Flights> <--- //$push? flights at array position [0] of OriginDestinationOption 
    }],
    'Inbound': [{
        <Inbound Flights> <-- // flights at array position [1] of OriginDestinationOption
    }]
},
...
```

The locations of the data for these in the JSON is:

```
Price: OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[x].AirItineraryPricingInfo[0].ItinTotalFare.TotalFare.Amount;
Inbound: OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[x].AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption[0]
Outbound: OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[x].AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption[1]
```

Comment: Would be really helpful if you could instead of giving a link to the data, just extract the parts that you need from the JSON file and edit your question to include a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok I'll look to do that - I did try and take a lot out of it via the online JSON editor...but I'll update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the current MongoDB release, the only way you can get results which are closer to what you want is by using the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)**, and working on the premise that the `OriginDestinationOption` array will have two elememts, you'd need the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** and **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)** operators to select the first and last elements in the array after the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator. For now (based on the above assumptions) you may have to do with running this pipeline:

```
db.flights.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary" },
    { "$unwind": "$OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary.AirItineraryPricingInfo" },
    { "$unwind": "$OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary.AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption" },    
    {
        "$project": {
            "Price": "$OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary.AirItineraryPricingInfo.ItinTotalFare.TotalFare.Amount",
            "DestinationOptions": "$OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary.AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption"
        }
    },    
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$Price",
            "Outbound" : { "$first": "$DestinationOptions" },
            "Inbound" : { "$last": "$DestinationOptions" }
        }
    }
])
```

which will yield the result (from the sample data):

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 269.56,
            "Outbound" : {
                "ElapsedTime" : 620,
                "FlightSegment" : [ 
                    {
                        "DepartureDateTime" : "2015-11-12T11:40:00",
                        "ArrivalDateTime" : "2015-11-12T17:35:00",
                        "StopQuantity" : 0,
                        "FlightNumber" : "1980",
                        "ElapsedTime" : 235,
                        "DepartureAirport" : {
                            "LocationCode" : "LHR",
                            "TerminalID" : "2",
                            "content" : ""
                        },
                        "ArrivalAirport" : {
                            "LocationCode" : "IST",
                            "TerminalID" : "I",
                            "content" : ""
                        },
                        "OperatingAirline" : {
                            "Code" : "TK",
                            "FlightNumber" : "1980",
                            "content" : ""
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "DepartureDateTime" : "2015-11-12T19:35:00",
                        "ArrivalDateTime" : "2015-11-13T02:00:00",
                        "StopQuantity" : 0,
                        "FlightNumber" : "760",
                        "ResBookDesigCode" : "W",
                        "ElapsedTime" : 265,
                        "DepartureAirport" : {
                            "LocationCode" : "IST",
                            "TerminalID" : "I",
                            "content" : ""
                        },
                        "ArrivalAirport" : {
                            "LocationCode" : "DXB",
                            "TerminalID" : "1",
                            "content" : ""
                        },
                        "OperatingAirline" : {
                            "Code" : "TK",
                            "FlightNumber" : "760",
                            "content" : ""
                        },
                        "Equipment" : [ 
                            {
                                "AirEquipType" : "343",
                                "content" : ""
                            }
                        ],
                        "MarketingAirline" : {
                            "Code" : "TK",
                            "content" : ""
                        },
                        "MarriageGrp" : "I",
                        "DepartureTimeZone" : {
                            "GMTOffset" : 2
                        },
                        "ArrivalTimeZone" : {
                            "GMTOffset" : 4
                        },
                        "TPA_Extensions" : {
                            "eTicket" : {
                                "Ind" : true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Inbound" : {
                "ElapsedTime" : 730,
                "FlightSegment" : [ 
                    {
                        "DepartureDateTime" : "2015-11-19T08:25:00",
                        "ArrivalDateTime" : "2015-11-19T11:40:00",
                        "StopQuantity" : 0,
                        "FlightNumber" : "763",
                        "ResBookDesigCode" : "W",
                        "ElapsedTime" : 315,
                        "DepartureAirport" : {
                            "LocationCode" : "DXB",
                            "TerminalID" : "1",
                            "content" : ""
                        },
                        "ArrivalAirport" : {
                            "LocationCode" : "IST",
                            "TerminalID" : "I",
                            "content" : ""
                        },
                        "OperatingAirline" : {
                            "Code" : "TK",
                            "FlightNumber" : "763",
                            "content" : ""
                        },
                        "Equipment" : [ 
                            {
                                "AirEquipType" : "330",
                                "content" : ""
                            }
                        ],
                        "MarketingAirline" : {
                            "Code" : "TK",
                            "content" : ""
                        },
                        "MarriageGrp" : "O",
                        "DepartureTimeZone" : {
                            "GMTOffset" : 4
                        },
                        "ArrivalTimeZone" : {
                            "GMTOffset" : 2
                        },
                        "TPA_Extensions" : {
                            "eTicket" : {
                                "Ind" : true
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "DepartureDateTime" : "2015-11-19T14:25:00",
                        "ArrivalDateTime" : "2015-11-19T16:35:00",
                        "StopQuantity" : 0,
                        "FlightNumber" : "1971",
                        "ResBookDesigCode" : "W",
                        "ElapsedTime" : 250,
                        "DepartureAirport" : {
                            "LocationCode" : "IST",
                            "TerminalID" : "I",
                            "content" : ""
                        },
                        "ArrivalAirport" : {
                            "LocationCode" : "LHR",
                            "TerminalID" : "2",
                            "content" : ""
                        },
                        "OperatingAirline" : {
                            "Code" : "TK",
                            "FlightNumber" : "1971",
                            "content" : ""
                        },
                        "Equipment" : [ 
                            {
                                "AirEquipType" : "32B",
                                "content" : ""
                            }
                        ],
                        "MarketingAirline" : {
                            "Code" : "TK",
                            "content" : ""
                        },
                        "MarriageGrp" : "I",
                        "DepartureTimeZone" : {
                            "GMTOffset" : 2
                        },
                        "ArrivalTimeZone" : {
                            "GMTOffset" : 0
                        },
                        "TPA_Extensions" : {
                            "eTicket" : {
                                "Ind" : true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

However, with the future releases (**[MongoDB 3.2 and newer](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2-reference/#development-reference-for-3-2-0-release-candidate)**), there are two operators **[`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2-reference/#exp._S_slice)** and **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2-reference/#exp._S_arrayElemAt)** which will work for you to produce the desired result. The **[`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2-reference/#exp._S_slice)** operator returns a subset of an array and the **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2-reference/#exp._S_arrayElemAt)** returns the element at the specified array index.

Thus you will implement the pipeline as follows -

**Case 1.** Using the **[`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2-reference/#exp._S_slice)** operator:

```
db.flights.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary" },
    { "$unwind": "$OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary.AirItineraryPricingInfo" },
    { "$unwind": "$OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary.AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption" },    
    {
        "$project": {
            "Price": "$OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary.AirItineraryPricingInfo.ItinTotalFare.TotalFare.Amount",
            "DestinationOptions": "$OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary.AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption"
        }
    },    
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$Price",
            "DestinationOptions" : { "$push": "$DestinationOptions" }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$project": { 
            "Inbound": { "$slice": [ "$DestinationOptions", 0, 1] },
            "Outbound": { "$slice": [ "$DestinationOptions", 1, 1 ] },
            "Price": "$_id",
            "_id": 0
        }
    }
])
```

**Case 2.** Using the **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2-reference/#exp._S_arrayElemAt)** operator:

```
db.flights.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary" },
    { "$unwind": "$OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary.AirItineraryPricingInfo" },
    { "$unwind": "$OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary.AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption" },    
    {
        "$project": {
            "Price": "$OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary.AirItineraryPricingInfo.ItinTotalFare.TotalFare.Amount",
            "DestinationOptions": "$OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary.AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption"
        }
    },    
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$Price",
            "DestinationOptions" : { "$push": "$DestinationOptions" }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$project": { 
            "Inbound": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$DestinationOptions", 0] },
            "Outbound": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$DestinationOptions", 1 ] },
            "Price": "$_id",
            "_id": 0
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the extensive reply. 3.2 looks like it has a nice set of tools for handling arrays like this. Thanks again :D

Comment: @dolyth No worries, glad to be of help. Indeed, 3.2 looks quite promising! :)

Comment: Sorry @chridam to ask another quick question in comments, if I wanted the Inbound/Outbound to be arrays containing the first/last results accumulatively.. could I use a $push or $addToSet in combo with $first/$last?

Comment: @dolyth That's the limitation with the current version, you cannot use a `$push` or `$addToSet` in combo with `$first/$last`. The only workaround I can suggest will be to create another `$group` pipeline stream (grouping by `_id`) preceding the one which has the `$first/$last`, and apply the `$push` or `$addToSet` operator on the `DestinationOptions` document.

Comment: Thanks again...I'll give that a go.